# Can Visualforce list links behave as related list links in Service Console?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console

I've just used openSubtab() successfully in a custom button to load a record in a new subtab in the Service Console, using the result[0].id returned from sforce.connection.create([record]).

I've also built some Custom Console Components as well that display lists of records in an apex:pageBlockTable that I would like to have the same functionality as a related list, to navigate to the individual records in their own subtabs, to save the user a click.

```
<apex:column width="50px" id="caseLink" headerValue="{!$ObjectType.case.fields.casenumber.label}" >
    <apex:outputLink value="/{!historyItem.Id}" onclick="myOpenSubtab({!historyItem.id})" >{!historyItem.caseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

If I wrap sforce.console.openSubtab() in a function myOpenSubtab(Id listItemId) that takes that {!historyItem.id} as a parameter, calling that function from the OnClick event of the link should do the trick, no?

I'm opening Cases in particular, so I created a Case-specific function for the purpose:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openCaseSubtab(id caseId) {

        var openCase = sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(response) {
            var primaryTabId = response.id;

            // create a Case detail url (with a default value of 500 (Case prefix))
            var url = "{!URLFOR($Action.Case.View, '500')}";

            // replace the Id with the Case.Id passed in to the function 
            url = url.replace("500", caseId);

            /* Define other parameters for openSubtab() */
            var isActive = true;
            var tabLabel = null;
            var subtabId = null;

            // Call the standard openSubtab method with the current Case's info
            var newCaseTab = sforce.console.openSubtab(
                primaryTabId, url, isActive, tabLabel, subTabId);

        });

    }
</script>
```

I'm getting the following errors:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL*

> Uncaught ReferenceError: srcUp is not defined

Anyone see anything obvious as far as how my function is implemented?  In the custom button, everything is contained within this

`sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(response) {
...
}`

and a new function per se is not required.  The openCase and newCaseTab variables were not necessary in the button implementation either; I added them here to prevent Compilation errors that prevented the page from saving.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue 1: Using a Visualforce expression

Would you try updating your `onclick` attribute? Right now it's written:

```
onclick="myOpenSubtab({!historyItem.id})"
```

I think it should be:

```
onclick="myOpenSubtab('{!historyItem.id}')"
```

The reason is that the Visualforce expression is evaluated as text and then injected into the HTML as the value, *without* any quotes. You need to manually add the quotes to delineate the value from the rest of the function call syntax.

### Issue 2: JavaScript function declaration

Would you remove the `id` text from your declaration of `openCaseSubtab()`? Right now you're declaring the JavaScript function as if you were declaring a method in Apex, which is incorrect. JavaScript [function parameters are not typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) (meaning you don't specify that the parameter needs to be an `Id` or a `List<Case>`). Your function declaration should look like this:

```
function openCaseSubtab(caseId) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The link output looks better now when I hover over the link (javascript:srcUp('https%3A%2F%2Fcs8.salesforce.com%2F500L0000005ngOMIAY%3Fisdtp%3Dvs'); if you must know), and the error has changed to Uncaught ReferenceError: openCaseSubtab is not defined, and Uncaught ReferenceError: srcUp is not defined.  I'm hoping that perhaps once the function is recognized the srcUp will resolve itself..?

Comment: There's another error right above those two: GET _https://test.salesforce.com/javascript/1426673431000/sfdc/source/SessionServer190.js.map 404 (Not Found)_   That's probably relevant.

Comment: onclick="openCaseSubtab('{!historyItem.Id}')" is the actual syntax, now, with the same spelling/case as the function... which makes 'openCaseSubtab is not defined' particularly annoying.  I'll recheck the function for punctuation errors.  ('myOpenSubtab' was a placeholder name)

Comment: <script src="/support/console/33.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script> precedes the <script></script> that contains the function, followed by a <style></style> and then the page details.  Just in case ordering has anything to do with unrecognized function.

Comment: @DuncanStewart I edited my answer to address another issue with the JavaScript code, where you delcare the function with an extraneous `id` in front of `caseId`.